# How to calculate the cell value in multiples based on the criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to build the logic in Excel where the value should get updated based on the Load criteria. I have attached an example where the row should update once the total of the cells in row 2 is in the multiples of load value. The logic should then take the difference i.e Total - Load and then recalculate for other corresponding cells

Any help will be really appreciated. Been trying to build this however not getting my head around it. Please see the below example

[image: 1688793403569.png]

I have tried below with the help of an earlier post, however, this doesn't give me output in multiples as expected.

```
=LET(load, B2, pay, C2:K2,first, TAKE(pay,,1),
REDUCE( IF(first>=load,load,0), SEQUENCE(,COUNTA(pay)-1,2),LAMBDA(a,b,LET( c, SUM(INDEX(pay,,SEQUENCE(,b-1))-a),d, c + INDEX(pay,,b),HSTACK( a, IF(d>=load,load,0))))))
```

Comment: Post data as text table and then show desired output.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean

Comment: You have put a screenshot of your data. Along with screenshot, put those data to post body as text so that we can copy and paste to our excel file. Also show, what output do you expect from given data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have found the solution.

```
=INT((SUM($C2:C2)-SUM($B3:B3))/$B2)*$B2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(load, B2,
      pay, C2:L2,
    first, TAKE(pay,,1),
REDUCE( IF(first>=load,load,0), SEQUENCE(,COUNTA(pay)-1,2),
LAMBDA( a, b,
   LET( c, SUM(INDEX(pay,,SEQUENCE(,b-1))-a),
        d, c+INDEX(pay,,b),
HSTACK(a,INT(d/load)*load)))))
```

This spills it in one go and uses the same logic kinda as the previous answer.